# abcpdf7 causing dev web server to crash

Tags: asp.net

This is my sample code from asp.net project

```
Doc abcpdfDoc = new Doc();
abcpdfDoc.MediaBox.String = "0 0 612 1008";
abcpdfDoc.Rect.String = abcpdfDoc.MediaBox.String;
abcpdfDoc.Page = abcpdfDoc.AddPage();
int docID

docID = abcpdfDoc.AddImageUrl(url_html.ToString()); //CAUSES webserver to crash
```

The code compiles with no warning/error. During debugging, I get a webserver crashed message - the following is the message

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: WebDev.WebServer.EXE
  Application Version:  9.0.30729.1
  Application Timestamp:    488f1aa2
  Fault Module Name:    ieframe.dll
  Fault Module Version: 9.0.8112.16457
  Fault Module Timestamp:   50a2fe39
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000d135b
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I am using abpdf7, downloaded the trial edition and ran the msi in admin mode using command line msiexec /i on win 7 running 32b OS

Comment: If you're downloading the trial version, why are you using v7 when the current version is v9?

Comment: Have legacy app running on v7 and that one is having issues, so i downloaded edition of v7 - locating the lic key - so using trial until then. Cannot upgrade to latest edition as customer will not bear cost and does not want code change for upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of crash is that the older version of the library does not work with IE 9.x, upgrading to latest version of library resolved the issue